# Why is it so difficult for a question of optimization to be answered?

Tags: support, answers, optimization

Except from questions [why this is faster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44485/how-should-we-handle-premature-optimization-discussion-in-optimization-questions) when somebody asks for a global optimization why is it so difficult for one to answer except from providing links?

**My personal point of view:** That's because for an optimization problem maths are needed and we can provide only code.

PS I really can't tell if this question is answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44485/how-should-we-handle-premature-optimization-discussion-in-optimization-questions) so it is just a duplicate, if so sorry.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimization is a fickle, fickle thing.

As an example, I worked on an application where the database would be backed up from production and used as the source data for QA and Dev.  This database was analyzed according to a schedule -- something that worked for production.  But this optimization didn't help for Dev and QA, which not only had different usage patterns, but wasn't updated nearly as frequently.

As a result, the speed of queries in Dev and QA went down, and we started to look at the possibility we had written code that changed something.  As we found out, no code had changed, just our assumptions.

Optimization is about assumptions. No one can give you a one-size-fits-all rule.  It all depends on your environment.

That's why those questions can't be answered objectively.

Answer (score 1):

Because "best" is subjective, and there are tradeoffs involved in investing time to investigate, rewrite, and redeploy changes which might make a particular thing "better".

Answer (score 1):

The *right* answer would often fill a large chapter or small book.

Which is to say, it does not fit in the Stack* format.

Comment: Yes, you could implement a script restricting large posts, too!